# Materialize CSS : Can't select text with mouse with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, materialize

I have built a site with MaterializeCSS. Everything is fine except that you can't  select text with the mouse when using IE9, with IE10 or better it's ok.

You can see this behaviour at http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html , you can't select text with the mouse when using IE9.

How do I enable text selection using a mouse with IE9 when a site is built with MaterializeCSS ?

Answer (score 1):

Materialize officially supports the following browsers according to their readme on GitHub at the moment of this post: Chrome 35+, Firefox 31+, Safari 7+, IE 10+
https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize

According to the following thread, there are no plans to support IE9 or lower in the future:
https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1230